# Is there an neovim plugin for mybatis?

Tags: java, ide, mybatis, neovim, neovim-plugin

1.recently code java in neovim. But i can not find a mybatis plugin in neovim.

2.need a neovim plugin when i code in mybatis xml files(just like myabtis plugin in other ides. eg:idea).

3.easy jump from mybatis mapper.java files to mybatis xml files